# The links in the top Answerers/Askers for a tag don't use the new search commands

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, search

I noticed today that the links in the top Answerers and Askers page for a tag don't use the new `is:Question` and `is:Answer` search criteria, so they return both questions and answers.

In addition, the Last 30 Days links in the first column does not use any kind of date filter on the search results that would only return results from the last 30 days.

For example, click on any link in the columns indicated below from any topusers-for-tag page, and you'll see the results are not filtered, and the # of results returned does not match the number displayed

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wpf/topusers

[image: Top Users page]

Comment: Did they ever? The `is:question` and `is:answer` commands aren't "new" (they existed with the previous search), so I'm assuming they just never thought about those things when building these lists. I don't believe there is any sort of date filter option, you'd just have to sort by newest.

Comment: @animuson I think they did, but can't be 100% positive. I recall going to that page once before and clicking on the link by my name to see which posts were included in that number, but that was over a year ago. I can't remember anything *not* working, so I'm assuming they were working correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was never the case...but we are showing you a number there so it makes sense we link you to what's relevant.  Starting in the next build with search will restrict on post type.  Note that the numbers will always be a little higher because we're showing community wiki posts in search results that aren't in the counts here.

If the community thinks it should match exactly and exclude those we can add `wiki:0` to the search as well.  I see both sides to that, so left it inclusive (as it was) for now.